# WIX Ref Project variable issue

Tags: c#, wix

My Wix Installer project references the service I want installed. The project name has periods in it, **MyProject.Client.Service**, and therefore I receive errors when compiling. Is my only options to rename the project so it doesn't have any periods in them? Or is there another way to ref this project?

I've tried updating the ref name, but nothing.

```
<?define MyProjectCompliedPath=$(var.MyProject.Client.Service.TargetDir)?>
```

[image: Highlighted does not work. The two above work fine]

[image: Visual Studio 2022 error]

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried this in a test project following your description using wix 3.11 and it does not produce any errors and warnings.
I've created a setup project referencing a c# library project having dots in it's name.

What i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
    <!-- TODO: Put your code here. -->
  <?define avar=$(var.ClassLibrary1df.df.df.TargetDir)?>
</Include>
```

and consuming the variable in a property.

```
<Property Id="hfhfh" Value="$(var.avar)"/>
```

Also using the variable in a file component worked just fine.

So maybe there is a different problem in your wix project.

Comment: I'm using VS2022. Wonder if it's an issue with the extension and it producing an incorrect compile time error. Error I receive is "Undefined preprocessor variable". I've updated the question with pictures.

Comment: Very odd. I removed the proj reference, then re-added, and now it works. Appreciate you confirming this does work.

Comment: Well, odd describes windows installers very well in general :). Glad at least this problem is solved.